# HQL query for primary key generation in hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have done my set of investigating before i could post a question here, 
I have an entity named "CODE" which i need to persist, to generate the primary key am currently using:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "CodeSequenceGenerator", sequenceName = "PRO_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "CodeSequenceGenerator", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "CODE_ID")
protected Long codeId;
```

This is resulting the ID to be selected from a temp table of the sequence specified. what i need is the ID to be selected from a particular table. I have a oracle query for it.

```
select seq(pro_seq, nextval)
from value_table v
where v.value >= 0
LIMIT 1
```

How do i write this into HQL and use it to get as the primary key for my entity?
Here the `seq(pro_seq,nextVal)` is the oracle function to get the latest sequence value.
I have been browsing about this issue a lot and have used `@TableGenerator` as well which did not work.
Please guide!

I did not try the Query because my database is not MYSQL i did try the Hibernate option given which did not work,  I even tried with table generator as shown below:

```
@TableGenerator(name = "ModifierSequenceGenerator", table = "CODE_VALUE", valueColumnName = "REFERENCE_SEQ.nextval", pkColumnName = "code_value")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "ModifierSequenceGenerator")
```

here there is another attribute pkColumnValue which if not mentioned will be taken as entity name as default.

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong you want next sequence value.

You can do that directly in MYSQL query like this. 
This gives last CODE_ID used. you can Increment this value and use.

```
SELECT CODE_ID FROM value_table ORDER BY CODE_ID DESC LIMIT 0,1;
```

Or if you want hibernate to handle this use this. By doing this you are telling to generate Id value automatically

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "CODE_ID", nullable = false)
```

Comment: I tired the approach suggested but it did not work .Anyways Thanks

Comment: I did not try the Query because my database is not MYSQL i did try the Hibernate option given which did not work,  I even tried with table generator as shown above :